# Iterate 4 Arrays with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, dictionary

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to build a nice application and I'm struggling with arrays, I have 4 arrays that I want to iterate and they are not the same size

I want to generate sections in HTML using the first array what I did it

```
@sections = ['Section One','Section Two','Section Three','Section Four']
@itemsOne = ['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4','item 5','item 6']
@itemsTwo = ['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4','item 5','item 6']
```

I was using

```
<%= @sections.zip(@itemsOne, @itemsTwo).each do |t1, t2, t3| %>
<%= t1 %>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= t2 %> | <%= t3 %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= t2 %> | <%= t3 %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= t2 %> | <%= t3 %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<% end %>
```

I have a table that have a **Section Title** and **cells** that have two values

but what I get is the value of `|t2|` in each cell of `|t1|` section
using `@Phil` answer down below, but he deleted it.

```
<%= @sections.zip(@itemsOne, @itemsTwo).each do |t| %>
<%= t[0] %>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= t[1] %> | <%= t[2] %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= t[1] %> | <%= t[2] %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= t[1] %> | <%= t[2] %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<% end %>
```

p.s. the itemsOne and itemsTwo arrays have more than 20 values.

Answer (score 0):

What I created is separated my big arrays into smaller ones and then Iterated thru each this way without a Table because table was making design issues so i went into div's using bootstrap 3 column, there might be a better way but this is what i got as a beginner.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

<h4><%= @Sections[0] %></h4>
<!-- This will Display Section 0 in the Array -->
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">

  <% @count = 0 %> 
  <!-- Counter is Zero -->
  <% @ItemsOne.collect do |t1| %> 
  <!-- This will loop array to increment the @count and repeat the HTML -->
  <% @count += 1 %>
  <!-- With each loop increment by 1-->

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">
      <%= @ItemsOne[@count - 1] %>
      <!-- Counter should start from 0 adding -1 will make it start
      from 0 instead of 1 and then will print the value of the Index Number  -->
      </label>
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this

```
<div class="row">
    <% @Sections.each_with_index do |x1, n| %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4><%= @Sections[n] %></h4>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <% if n == 0 %>
    <% @itemsOne.each_with_index do |t1, n| %>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">
            <%= @itemsOne[n] %>
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% elsif n == 1 %>
    <% @itemsTwo.each_with_index do |t1, n| %>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">
                <%= @itemsTwo[n] %>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>

<% elsif n == 2 %>
    <% @itemsThree.each_with_index do |t1, n| %>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">
                 <%= @itemsThree[n] %> 
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

<% elsif n == 3 %>
    <% @itemsFour.each_with_index do |t1, n| %>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">
                <%= @itemsFour[n] %> 
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

<% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>

</div>
```